# Radials with centre-loading coil

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, hf, vertical-antenna, radial

Does a centre-loaded HF antenna need radials? If I put a loading coil 1,5-2m (5-6,5 feet) high, do I need to put radials out on the ground? Feed point would still be near the ground.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, if it is a current-fed antenna, i.e. a quarter wave, or odd multiple thereof (3/4,5/4, etc.); if it is a λ/2 antenna, or even multiple thereof, then no, it does not need radials.

Whether or not your λ/4 HF vertical antenna uses a loading coil, it will benefit from radials, but at a minimum, must have a counterpoise.

You may also be interested to check out the question, "[What do radials really do for a vertical antenna?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/18516/what-do-radials-really-do-for-a-vertical-antenna)" and its answers for additional relevant information!